# Use default font for creating zebra zpl code?

Tags: printing, zebra-printers, zpl

I created a template that includes some params like this:
{PARAM_1}, {PARAM_2}
and I replace template params to generate label zpl code.
I'm using it for creating zpl code, zebra designer in windows and I use save to file button.

But I have a problem when I choose Zebra0 font or TimesNewRoman zpl encode param like that:

**FONT: Zebra0 (LOOK GOOD)**

```
{PARAM_1} => 
^FT106,274^A0N,21,20^FH\^CI28^FD{PARAM_1}^FS^CI27
```

**FONT: TimesNewRoman (There is no {PARAM_1})**

```
{PARAM_1} => ^FO106,213^GFA,333,580,20,:Z64:eJy90bFqwzAQBuBfOlei1BS83RBo8gYePbZv0dGPkCdIZQzpEjr3MfIGubyJHqHQpVPdkyowMenaAw33cUh3J+AfQhY5A2ac4PAS0ZKYCMQasDgHB+7QQkwARQutEfHgFTpECkBP2fo7cI3nq3a8KebVmqB2KOYB+jVWe79N5rJJI7zF22ypl7U8iHE4NMm0lwrfWAvPZtIoolNwpAn7bJpXeh577i1hvyl1NtmWW0th3JT79F2ElrvKhPFp7iXZSm04F/NpHR3f10aGoczh6MPH3c6f6DO+RpivvINF/GF2aQq678uor//bRfgpV/wA6IJP7g==:C45B
```

I want to use Calibri font for parameters, how can i use ?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

What you see in the print to file when you use a non zebra font is a graphic field, which is the result of the conversion of the text field into a graphic field. This happens because the font used is not installed on the printer, so the printer is not capable to process that font and the only solution is the conversion into a graphic field that the printer can manage.
Have a look [here](https://www.thezcorner.com/printers/fonts/printers-using-a-font-when-printing-from-zebradesigner) for additional info.
If you want to use Calibri to print, you need to [install the font](https://www.thezcorner.com/printers/fonts/printers-download-a-font-to-the-printer-memory) and then [recall](https://www.thezcorner.com/printers/fonts/printers-using-a-font-when-sending-zpl-code) it at the beginning of the ZPL, if you want to use it for all the text field, or you can recall it in each single text field.

Comment: I can use calibri as static text but I cant use as a field variable. I think this is not solution for me

Comment: are you going to print from zebradesigner or are by sending the code from a software or in other way like socket connection?

Comment: I tried to export to file as zpl format.

Comment: ok and what it is the {PARAM_1}? a variable? can you post a picture of the designed label in zebradesigner and the expected outcome?

Comment: https://ibb.co/m8kdCjb

Comment: If I understood correctly, the stuff within the braces are the variable data and, in this case, the info I've provided earlier can be used to solve this problem. I don't know how you're going to print the final label (if you're using zebradesigner pro and you've connected a database to feed the variable data or you're going to use the exported zpl into a software which sends the data directly), but, whatever is going to be, if you need to print variable data with the calibri font and you need to see the clear data in the zpl, you definitely need to install the font on the printer

Comment: thanks for your detailed answer, I dont feed data from database. I just create a simple template with replacable parameters, read and replace it with our data on the fly. I'll tried install calibri font but i couldt recall it, still investigating...